# Postgres last date from previous month

Tags: postgresql

Looking for a date function to update a postgres table with the last date from previous month. Any idea?

Henri

Answer (score 3):

The last date of the previous month is simply the day before the beginning of this month:

```
SELECT date_trunc('month',now()) - '1 day'::interval;
```

Substitute `now()` with the date you are interested in, if different.

Answer (score 0):

as per the wiki https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Date_LastDay

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION last_day(DATE)
RETURNS DATE AS
$$
  SELECT (date_trunc('MONTH', $1) + INTERVAL '1 MONTH - 1 day')::DATE;
$$ LANGUAGE 'sql' IMMUTABLE STRICT;
```

and just substract a month from your date